# Question about types of motion in ITF Taekwon-do

Tags: tae-kwon-do, itf

In ITF Taekwon-Do, what are the main differences between:

1. Continuous motion
2. Connecting motion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Continuous motion** - links movements with no pause between the end of one movement and the start of another. Breathe in once, then breathe out in a continuous flow of air.

**Connecting motion** - completes a movement with one breath and one sinewave.

The breath should emphasize that the movements within continuous motion are not ending movements - they support the final movement.  (Otherwise, you have no breath left for the remaining movements).  The breath usually should emphasize that the movements within are also not power movements - they're supporting movements.

It is said that continuous motion begins with a block.  I am trying to find out where in the encyclopedia that is stated, but it's hard because my copy is image-only, not searchable text.  However, that the word "block" is used suggests a misunderstanding of the technique, since blocks can be strikes and throws (and vice-versa), and so it's not clear why the stipulation of "block" is mentioned.

It is also stated that connecting motion begins with one arm, and ends with the other (opposite arms).  I think this is an error in translation; connecting motion begins on one "side" (not necessarily on one arm), and ends with the other side.

**Source**: *Encyclopedia, Vol II (Gen Choi, Hong Hi)*, p31:

"One breath is required for one movement, with the exception of a continuous motion".

I suspect that the opposite arm and that thing about blocks is an interpretation loosely based on this tenet.  I suspect that it's true in some cases, but not all cases.  Such discussion of movements has never been a lengthy subject in my classes.